# AWS Cognito User Pool External OIDC Provider Integration

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

I'm using AWS Cognito App Client integration with an external OIDC provider.

The authorization endpoint requires the following attributes:

```
GET /authorize?response_type=code
&scope=YOUR_SCOPES
&client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID
&state=STATE
&redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
&nonce=aEwkamaos5B
&vtr=["Cl.Cm"]
&ui_locales=en
```

Nonce:

- Required
- A unique value generated by your application that is used to verify the integrity of the id_token and mitigate replay attacks.
  This value will be present in the id_token and should include the per-session state, as well as being impossible for attackers to guess.
  Your application will need to verify the nonce claim value is the same as the nonce parameter sent in the authentication request.

Is it possible to configure Cognito to send this nonce value?

Thanks

From what I can see nonce is a required paramater which Cognito does not send as part of the OAuth flow causing the OIDC provider to reject the request. I have used postman to simulate the Authorization request using a nonce to the OIDC provider which returns a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Cognito will support sending a `nonce` parameter, since it should not be required these days. It was used in the following OpenID Connect flows:

```
implicit: response_type=token id_token
hybrid: response_type=code token id_token
```

Both of these returned an ID token response on the front channel, which would include the `nonce` from the authentication request as a claim.

There were risks that a malicious party could insert their own ID token, so the client had to validate the ID token and check that its nonce had the expected value.

These days it is less recommended to return ID tokens in this manner, eg since it may leak personally identifiable information such as names and emails in the browser history or server logs.

It is now simpler and more standard to use the code flow, via this request parameter. Only the authorization code is then received on the front channel, with all tokens are received via back channel requests. Federated OIDC connections typically use this option, and don't send the `nonce` parameter:

```
response_type=code
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately the service I'm using requires a nonce param :/